# Julia 1.1 How to use JDL or JDL2 to actively write indexed matrix data into a file on the disk?

Tags: arrays, file, julia

I'm using Julia 1.1 and thankfully both JDL and JDL2 seemed to be working.

I want to create a 3d matrix to save into a file, indexed in $(x,y,z)$, which is not too had with just

```
using JLD 
save("File_name","variable_name",variable)
```

Suppose I have already done that, i.e.

```
using JLD 
save("some_file","Matrix_t", M_T)
```

where M_T was a blank 3d zero array.

Then I want to save frames of sequential data with respect to $z$ axis (like matfile function in Matlab), so that each time I can save a 2d array into an indexed place in M_T in file "some_file".

I read about the usage of g_create "group". However, they used name with semicolon, and I doubt if that's want I wanted.

Could you help me to save the sequential data in a 3d Matrix actively into a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want through [Memory Mapped I/O](https://en.wikipedi.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) since `JLD.jl` supports memory mapped arrays.

The following snippet will create a 3-dimensional array of type `Float64` and save it into a `JLD` file.

```
using JLD
A = zeros(100, 100, 100)
save("mmap.jld", "A", A)
```

Now, let us open the file in another Julia session and read `A` as a memory-mapped array. Note that memory-mapped I/O will not load all the array into memory at once, so you will *not*, hopefully, run out of memory even if the array in the file is very large.

```
using JLD
file = jldopen("mmap.jld", "r+", mmaparrays = true) # `r+` important if you want to modify the array
A = read(file, "A")
```

`A` is a memory-mapped array. You can use it as if it is an ordinary 3D `Array`. The modifications on `A` will be written into the file on disk. (Although you might want to use `using Mmap; Mmap.sync!(A)` after all the changes just to make sure the changes are really written on the disk, but I am not sure of this one though.)

Now, we will change the content

```
A[:,:,1] .= 100
# close the file
close(file)
```

You can now close this session and try to open the file in another session to see the effect.

Note that you need to make `A` garbage collected if you want to open the jld file again in the *same* session (i.e. `A = []; GC.gc()`). Otherwise the file lock will be kept, since `A` is memory-mapped into the file. This is not necessary if you already close the session.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it. (Just a little notes for new beginners like me. I tried it out by using a 3.5 GB array, the command "A = read(file, "A")" in deed does not read the file into the memory, but the "variable" A can be used just like a normal matrix and the changes on A happened simultaneously on the disk.)